# entity framework error on db generation

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I restructured part of my db into a new db (using mySQL). On importing it into my website project I get 62 errors all stating "Reference required to assembly System.Core Version=4.0.0.0". So naturally I try to add it and VS says its already referenced. I've tried numerous things to fix including rerunning the code generation tool, re-saving the diagram but nothing works and those errors still exist, any thoughts?

Comment: What's the target framework for the project? It's probably a conflict between that and whatever framework version is referenced in the mySQL library (no idea which that would be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution was rather easy, I just added my own entry in the web config from the info in the error. Adding this line resolved the problem.

```
 <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```